# Reading filenames from a zip file inside another zip file

Tags: php, zip, filenames

I am trying to get all filenames from the files inside a zip file. It all works perfectly until the zip file contains another zip file and I try to get the included file names from the included zip as well.
I want to get all included filenames without extracting the file.

For some reason it always refuses to open the included zip file, as if it does not recognie it as a zip file.
To make 100% sure it is a zip for testing I simply included the same zip inside the main zip.
While it properly reads the main zipfile it returns false if I want to read the included file.

I have been trying to get this script to work for 3 days now but I keep failing so I decided to see if someone here can help me out with this.

This is the script I am using to read a zipfile contents:

```
function firstzipper($file) {

    global $filesroot, $pagefile;
    $zipinc = new ZipArchive();
    if ($zipinc->open($file) === TRUE) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $zipinc->numFiles; $i++) {
            $filename_full = $zipinc->getNameIndex($i);
            $filename = substr($filename_full, strrpos($filename_full, '/') + 1);
            if (!is_dir($filename)) {
                $filename = filter_var($filename, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                if ($ext == 'zip') {
                    secondzipper($filesroot.$pagefile.'/'.$filename_full);
                }
            }
            array_push($inc_files_arr,$filename);
        }
        return $inc_files_arr;
    }

}
```

firstzipper($filesroot.$url);

secondzipper inside the function above is simply the same function, copied and renamed.

The zipfile looks like this:
E:/myfolder/fileserver/temper.zip/myincluded.zip

The function opens temper.zip but returns false on myincluded.zip.

I hope I have included all info needed, if not let me know and I add what else is required.

Comment: _I want to get all included filenames without extracting the file_ - This cannot be done with `ZipArchive`

Comment: Why am I able to get all included filenames of a zipfile with my above function then?

ZipArchive::getNameIndex -- Returns the name of an entry using its index
So to me this means it is not extracting to begin with.

Comment: I'm not saying it is not possible in the general case - I am saying it is not possible with `ZipArchive`. You can list the files within a ZIP file, but not a ZIP file within a ZIP file.

Comment: Ok, I understand. So my efforts were useless :)

Since you mention it is not possible with ZipArchive, would you happen to know another way to do it?